# How can I use generics to create Spring Boot Service classes

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I would like to use generics to create an abstract service that can be subclassed

So far I have created 3 entities:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "logging_event_base")
abstract class LoggingEventBaseEntity constructor(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        val id: Long = -1,

        @Column(name = "tracking_id")
        private val trackingID: String = "",

        @Column(name = "descriptive_message")
        private val descriptiveMessage: String = "",

        @Column(name = "message_code")
        private val messageCode: String = "",

        @Column(name = "time_stamp")
        private val timeStamp: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "loggingEvent", cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
        val messageContentLogging: LoggingEventContentEntity? = null) {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "loggingEvent", cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
    private val _properties: MutableSet<LoggingEventPropertyEntity> = mutableSetOf()

    val properties: Set<LoggingEventPropertyEntity>
        get() = _properties

    fun addProperty(property: LoggingEventPropertyEntity) {
        this._properties.add(property)
    }

    fun addProperty(name: String, value: String) {
        this.addProperty(LoggingEventPropertyEntity(name = name, value = value))
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "logging_event_log")
class LoggingEventLogEntity(
        id: Long = -1, trackingID: String = "", descriptiveMessage: String = "",
        messageCode: String = "", timeStamp: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        messageContentLogging: LoggingEventContentEntity? = null,

        @Column(name = "log_level")
        var logLevel: String = "",

        @Column(name = "log_status")
        var logStatus: String = "")
    : LoggingEventBaseEntity(id, trackingID, descriptiveMessage, messageCode, timeStamp, messageContentLogging) {  }

@Entity
@Table(name = "logging_event_exception")
class LoggingEventExceptionEntity(
        id: Long = -1, trackingID: String = "", descriptiveMessage: String = "",
        messageCode: String = "", timeStamp: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        messageContentLogging: LoggingEventContentEntity? = null,

        @Column(name = "error_type")
        val errorType: ErrorEventTypes = ErrorEventTypes.UNKNOWN,

        @Column(name = "status")
        val status: ErrorEventStatuses = ErrorEventStatuses.OPEN,

        @Column(name = "stack_trace")
        val stackTrace: String = "")
    : LoggingEventBaseEntity(id, trackingID, descriptiveMessage, messageCode, timeStamp, messageContentLogging) {}
```

3 repositories:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface LoggingEventBaseRepository<T : LoggingEventBaseEntity> : CrudRepository<T, Long>

@Transactional
interface LoggingEventRepository : LoggingEventBaseRepository<LoggingEventBaseEntity>

@Transactional
interface LoggingEventLogRepository : LoggingEventBaseRepository<LoggingEventLogEntity>

@Transactional
interface LoggingEventExceptionRepository : LoggingEventBaseRepository<LoggingEventExceptionEntity>
```

And 3 service interfaces:

```
interface LoggingEventBaseService<T : LoggingEventBaseEntity> {
    fun retrieveLogs(): List<T>

    fun retrieveLog(id: Long): T?

    fun addLog(loggingEvent: T): T
}

interface LoggingEventLogService : LoggingEventBaseService<LoggingEventLogEntity>

interface LoggingEventExceptionService : LoggingEventBaseService<LoggingEventExceptionEntity>
```

Which should be implemented with the following classes:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA<E: LoggingEventBaseEntity, out R: LoggingEventBaseRepository<E>>(
        val loggingEventRepository: R,
        val logPropertyRepository: LoggingEventPropertyRepository,
        val logMessageContentRepository: LoggingEventContentRepository) : LoggingEventLogService {

    override fun retrieveLogs(): E = loggingEventRepository.findAll().toList()

    override fun retrieveLog(id: Long): E? = loggingEventRepository.findById(id).orElse(null)

    override fun addLog(loggingEvent: E): LoggingEventLogEntity {
        loggingEvent.properties.forEach {
            it.loggingEvent = loggingEvent
            logPropertyRepository.save(it)
        }

        loggingEvent.messageContentLogging?.let { logMessageContentRepository.save(it) }

        return loggingEventRepository.save(loggingEvent)
    }
}



@Service
@Transactional
class LoggingEventLogServiceJPA: LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA<LoggingEventLogEntity, LoggingEventLogRepository>, LoggingEventLogService

@Service
@Transactional
class LoggingEventExceptionServiceJPA: LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA<LoggingEventExceptionEntity, LoggingEventExceptionRepository>, LoggingEventLogService
```

I'm running into a couple of issues here:

1. In the `LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA` constructor `val loggingEventRepository: R` shows an error `Could not autowire. No beans of 'R' type found`
2. `override fun retrieveLogs(): E = loggingEventRepository.findAll().toList()` shows an error `Return type is 'E', which is not subtype of overwridden`
3. The same error is show on `override fun retrieveLog(id: Long): E? = loggingEventRepository.findById(id).orElse(null)`
4. Because I subclass `LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA`, the parameters should be passed to this superclass. This does make sense, but this should be solved using autowiring in some way.

Does anyone know what would be a proper approach in these situations, where the Entity is subclassed, so the Repositories and Services need to have subclasses too? The goal in this case is to keep everything as DRY and maintainable as possible.

It might be that I took a complete wrong approach from the start, so please let me know if you think that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using Composition instead of inheritance to create the concrete Service classes.

```
interface LoggingEventBaseService<T : LoggingEventBaseEntity> {
    fun retrieveLogs(): List<T>    
    fun retrieveLog(id: Long): T?    
    fun addLog(loggingEvent: T): T
}

interface LoggingEventLogService : LoggingEventBaseService<LoggingEventLogEntity>

interface LoggingEventExceptionService : LoggingEventBaseService<LoggingEventExceptionEntity>


class LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA<E : LoggingEventBaseEntity>(
        private val loggingEventRepository: LoggingEventBaseRepository<E>) : LoggingEventBaseService<E> {

    override fun retrieveLogs(): List<E> = loggingEventRepository.findAll().toList()

    override fun retrieveLog(id: Long): E? = loggingEventRepository.findById(id).orElse(null)

    override fun addLog(loggingEvent: E): E {
        loggingEvent.properties.forEach {
            it.loggingEvent = loggingEvent
        }

        loggingEvent.messageContentLogging?.let {
            it.loggingEvent = loggingEvent
        }

        return loggingEventRepository.save(loggingEvent)
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional
class LoggingEventLogServiceJPA(loggingEventRepository: LoggingEventLogRepository)
    : LoggingEventLogService {

    private val base = LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA(loggingEventRepository)

    override fun retrieveLogs(): List<LoggingEventLogEntity> {
        return base.retrieveLogs()
    }

    override fun retrieveLog(id: Long): LoggingEventLogEntity? {
        return base.retrieveLog(id)
    }

    override fun addLog(loggingEvent: LoggingEventLogEntity): LoggingEventLogEntity {
        return base.addLog(loggingEvent)
    }
}
```

The base service class is just a plain POKO, without any annotations.

The concrete implementations have the `@Service` and `@Transactional` annotations, making them discoverable by Spring.

This way I still get some duplicate code, but also a lot of freedom when a Subclass would need just a bit of other functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider delegation like this?

```
@Service
@Transactional
class LoggingEventLogServiceJPA(loggingEventRepository: LoggingEventLogRepository)
    : LoggingEventLogService by base {

    private val base = LoggingEventBaseServiceJPA(loggingEventRepository)

}
```